# My Windows 11 Hyper V Session suddenly switching monitors

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v

Today after over 2 years without any issues, when I open the single Windows 11 environment I have running in Hyper V it is switching 2 of the monitors. I have a 3 monitor setup on my PC and I have my Hyper V sessions running across all 3. When I minimize the Hyper V session it shows in the taskbar for the middle and right monitor. When I maximize, the screen flashes black for about 5 seconds and then the middle and left monitors have flip! So if I do it a second time, it goes back to how it originally was!

I tried rebooting the Hyper V Windows 11 sessions, my desktop Windows 11. I checked for windows updates on both and saw nothing needed updated. I also checked my desktops NVidia drivers and nothing was out of date there either. I also tried disconnecting monitors one at a time and reconnecting them and that did not solve the issue.
Any idea how to fix this?